# Use encrypted /home in fresh Debian created in Mint

Tags: debian, linux-mint, ecryptfs

I usually use my Linux Mint 15 installation on my PC. I have separate `/` and `/home` partitions. `/home` is encrypted with ecryptfs, which I did not configure myself, I just ticked the "encrypt home" when installing Mint.

I have today installed Debian, with it's own `/`-partition. I also chose the same `/home` partition I use on Mint, because I want to share all files in `/home` between the two. I was hoping that Debian would automatically recognize `/home` as encrypted with ecryptfs and decrypt it for me with my user password. But it did not. When I log in on Debian I get this error message:

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/fridge/.ICEauthority.
```

My only option is to log out.

The `/etc/fstab` entry in Mint does not mention `ecryptfs` anywhere, `/home` is just mounted as `ext4`. That was my first thought, that it would mount in `fstab`.

How do I configure Debian to automatically decrypt `/home` for me when I log in?

---

**EDIT:** I belive I misunderstood the problem! Today I started up Debian and instead of logging in through the greeter I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2 and logged in through the command line. The `/home` partition was decrypted! Apparently Debian does that for you like Mint. I tried `startx` but encountered the same problem as I was logging in through the GUI `xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/fridge/.Xauthority`. Should I close this question now?

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-encrypt-directories-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian-squeeze - part 4 maybe ?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith The article you linked uses an entierly diffrent way to decrypt it though. There a key is put on a usb drive which is mounted in fstab. This is not how Mint set it up to work!

Comment: Debian doesn't set up ecryptfs automatically during system installation, it's more hands-on than Ubuntu or Mint. Have you installed the `ecryptfs` package?

Comment: @Gilles I have `chroot`ed into Debian and installed `ecryptfs-utils` and tried to poke around at things. Thing is I don't know where (in the configuration, not fs) the mount should be done.